# Openssl in windows issue

Tags: c, openssl, visual-c++

While I try to create lib files for windows.The following error came.
Please help on this issue.

**CODE Explanation**

This Line I actually typed in visual studio command prompt.This will create the obj and dll files for OpenSSL.

```
   X:\dev\openssl>nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
```

It start executing make files to get the lib and obj files.

```
   Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86

   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   Building OpenSSL
    cl /Fotmp32dll\err_all.obj -Iinc32 -Itmp32dll /MD /Ox /O2 /Ob2 -O -  DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK -I. -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE /I "C:\Program Files\Microsoft    SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Include" /I "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\VC\INCLUDE" /Zi   /Fdtmp32dll/lib -D_WINDLL -DOPENSSL_BUILD_SHLIBCRYPTO -c .\crypto\err\err_all.c
```

The Error is throwing in this file only.When it tries to include this file ocsp.h.

```
    err_all.c
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(157) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(206) : error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(206) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(208) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(209) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(350) : error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(350) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(352) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(404) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
       X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2143: syntax error : missing     ')' before '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2091: function returns function
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2091: function returns function
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{'        before 'constant'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(405) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
      X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(406) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')'         before '('
        X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2091: function returns function
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2091: function returns function
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
      X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(407) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2091: function returns function
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2091: function returns function
      X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2143: syntax error : missing   '{' before 'constant'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
  X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
  X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(409) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
  X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2091: function returns function
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2091: function returns function
        X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
  X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(416) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(418) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(420) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(420) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(420) : error C2091: function returns function
 X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(420) : error C2091: function returns function

  X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')'         before '('
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
  X:\dev\ openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2091: function returns function
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2091: function returns function
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(425) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(427) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(427) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')'  before '('
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(427) : error C2091: function returns function
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(427) : error C2091: function returns function
       X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(427) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
      X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(427) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(427) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('
   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2091: function returns function
  X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2091: function returns function
  X:\dev \openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
      X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
        X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(428) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
      X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(430) : error C2143: syntax error : missing   ')' before '('
    X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(430) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '('

   X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(430) : error C2059: syntax error : '<Unknown>'
  X:\dev\ openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(430) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
      X:\dev \openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(435) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(437) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')'  before '('
```

The compilation stops here:

```
     X:\dev\openssl\inc32\openssl/ocsp.h(437) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds  100; stopping compilation
     cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'O' has been deprecated and will be rem
    oved in a future release
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\VC\Bin
    \cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
   Stop.
```

Comment: Did you run vcvars32.bat before nmake?

Comment: Having the same problem, almost seven years later.

Answer (score 5):

Have been fighting the same issue with a MinGW cross-compile on Linux.

Looking at the pre-processed source the issues are obvious:

```
typedef struct ocsp_request_st
 {
 OCSP_REQINFO *tbsRequest;
 OCSP_SIGNATURE *optionalSignature;
 } ((LPCSTR) 66)

struct ocsp_responder_id_st
 {
 int type;
 union {
  ((LPCSTR) 7)* byName;
         ASN1_OCTET_STRING *byKey;
  } value;
 };
```

Somehow the ***OPENSSL_SYS_WIN32*** specific #undef block in ***crypto/ossl_typ.h*** seems to have no effect.

Explicitly adding

```
#undef OCSP_REQUEST
#undef X509_NAME
#undef OCSP_RESPONSE
```

before

```
#include <openssl/ocsp.h>
```

in ***crypto/err/err_all.c*** fixes it.

Unfortunately I hit another issue afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

These are the command line calls I issue to build OpenSSL static libs in MSVS.  I assume they should work the same substituting the dll makefile you're calling, as well.

```
call "%VS90COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
perl Configure VC-WIN32
call ms\do_nasm
nmake -f ms\nt.mak clean
nmake -f ms\nt.mak
```

You can find NASM here:  [www.nasm.us](http://www.nasm.us/)

Answer (score 0):

First I got the same error. 
Maybe this was because I did not start correctly the first time ?
So I just erased the whole working folder openssl-1.0.1e
Extracted a fresh tar file in the folder

Started visual studio 2012 command prompt as admin 
( VS2012 x86 native tools command prompt ... runAs Administrator)
Added perl and nasm to the path
perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=c:\openssl
call ms\do_nasm
nmake -f ms\nt.mak

everything ok ..